# Flexible search in database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a legacy system that allows users to manage some entities called "TRANSACTION" in the (MySQL) DB, and mapped to Transaction class in Java. Transaction objects have about 30 fields, some of them are columns in the DB, some of them are joins to another tables, like CUSTOMER, PRODUCT, COMPANY and stuff like that.

Users have access to a "Search" screen, where they are allowed to search using a TransactionId and a couple of extra fields, but they want more flexibility. Basically, they want to be able to search using any field in TRANSACTION or any linked table.

I don't know how to make the search both flexible and quick. Is there any way?. I don't think that having an index for every combination of columns is a valid solution, but full table scans are also not valid... is there any reasonable design? I'm using Criteria to build the queries, but this is not the problem.

Also, I think mysql is not using the right indexes, since when I make hibernate log the sql command, I can almost always improve the response time by forcing an index... I'm starting to use something like [this trick](http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/10/07/using-use-index-with-hibernatemysql/) adapted to Criteria to force a specific index use, but I'm not proud of the "if" chain. I'm getting something like

```
if(queryDto.getFirstName() != null){
    //force index "IDX_TX_BY_FIRSTNAME"
}else if(queryDto.getProduct() != null){
    //force index "IDX_TX_BY_PRODUCT"
}
```

and it feels horrible

Sorry if the question is "too open", I think this is a typical problem, but I can't find a good approach

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is very good for writing while SQL still excels on reading data. [JOOQ](http://blog.jooq.org/) might be a better alternative in your case, and since you're using MySQL it's free of charge anyway.

[JOOQ is like Criteria on steroids](http://vladmihalcea.com/jooq-facts-from-jpa-annotations-to-jooq-table-mappings/), and you can build more complex queries using the exact syntax you'd use for native querying. You have type-safety and all features your current DB has to offer.

As for indexes, you need can't simply use any field combination. It's better to index the most used ones and try using compound indexes that cover as many use cases as possible. Sometimes the query executor will not use an index because it's faster otherwise, so it's not always a good idea to force the index. What works on your test environment might not stand still for the production system.